# Issues while connecting an external display to my MacBook Air 2015 using a DisplayPort adaptor

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display, hdmi, displayport

The other day I started having a random issue connecting an 1080p external display to my connected to my MacBook Air 2015 using a Mini DisplayPort to HDMI adaptor that I've used for about 6 months. The external monitor  doesn't receive any signal. I've thought "It's no biggie, I already replaced like 5 of those, so I'll just order a new one.". Today, I tried with the new adapter, and nothing happens, just like before.

The issue is that the display doesn't receive any signal, but detects that there is some device connected to it, yet my MacBook, apparently, does not. Also, when I connect it to the external monitor the computer freezes in burst of 2 or 3 seconds, with some 2 second pauses, for about 5 times, I guess it is trying to connect.

I've tried:

- restarting my computer
- detect a display (with the Option key)
- some of my old adaptors
- using a brand new HDMI cable (and many old ones, that worked with other devices)
- using some different monitors (all of them were 1080p)
- using my old Linux installation (which also worked before)
- using Apple Diagnostics (CMD-D when booting — it reported no failure)
- formatting my whole SDD and reinstalling MacOS
- updating to the latest MacOS version
- reseting my PRAM/NVRAM
- reseting my SMC
- booting into Safe Mode

Maybe some info, that might help you is the Thunderbolt section in the System Information, while my adaptor is connected: [image: Thunderbolt section in the System Information]

Comment: Which brand and model MDP > HDMI adapter are you using? My workplace tested many different manufacturers and found that many adapters either didn't work at all, worked poorly, or had inferior build quality that lead to early physical deterioration. After testing, the [Belkin MDP > HDMI 4k model](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-DisplayPort-Adapter-Compatible-Black/dp/B013P0JTX0) stood the test of time. It is well constructed and withstands abuse.

Comment: @IconDaemon I was using this [Hama model](https://www.amazon.com/Video-Adapter-DisplayPort-Socket-Black/dp/B00Y9WF27Q/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=mini+displayport+to+hdmi+hama&qid=1586367871&sr=8-1) and now I'm using an of brand one that I've used before, and worked for about 1 year.
Also I can't really access Amazon in my country.

Comment: It’s likely your port.  It’s a Thunderbolt 2 port.  So, get an inexpensive adapter like a Thunderbolt to Ethernet adapter and see if that works.